# Is it required to construct a future with constructor when function returns a future?

Tags: dart

In case of function returns a Future, should I return pure `bool` or construct a future with bool?

```
Future<bool> loginSite() async {
 ...
 return Future.value(false); 
 // or
 // return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is marked `async` simply use `return false`. It's easier to read and it has the same behaviour.

Side note: there's even a language request to [disallow returning futures from `async` functions.](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/870)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `async`, you can simply ignore `Future.value` and return `bool`:

```dart
Future<bool> f() async { // <-- Has async
  // ...
  return false;
}
```

In absence of `async`, use `Future.value`:

```dart
Future<bool> f() { // <-- Doesn't have async
  // ...
  return Future.value(false);
}
```